# Get product collection based on entity_id in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, collection, tags

How to Create product collection with filter based on `entity_id` in Magento 2?

I tried below:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\MOdule\Model\Queue');
$ProductId = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['entity_id'];
$getId = $tagmodel->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $ProductId);

// Tried this too
/*  
   $getId=$model->getCollection()->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$ProductId);   */
if ($getId = '') {
    $tagmodel->setEntityId($ProductId);
    $tagmodel->save();
}
```

I am  not getting the collection! nor the id is saved

My id should no be saved if already present in DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update behaviour in csv not working as expected](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129890/update-behaviour-in-csv-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

If the `entity_id` is key of the model, try this:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\MOdule\Model\Queue');
$ProductId = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['entity_id'];
$getId = $tagmodel->load($ProductId);

if (!$getId->getId()) {
    $tagmodel->setEntityId($ProductId);
    $tagmodel->save();
}
```

Comment: Siarhey, i m trying to add only those product ids which are updated via csv import. For eg i have 2 product ids 1 and 2... i updated only one id and when i upload only that id which i updated should be saved in table

Comment: I get the ids correctly if i log $ProductId , but saving is the issue!

Comment: Better not use the objectManager this way, check out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I know, but this is the source code from the question

Comment: @SachinS Could you update the question with full code?

Comment: Siarhey, i have updated the code with full scenario here...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129890/update-behaviour-in-csv-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @SachinS to help the quality of this platform, don't cross-reference questions and answers. This will make it hard for future readers encountering the same problem. If the code is needed to answer this question here, please update the question as well.

Comment: Ok sure... @Anna

Comment: @Siarhey, any update from my code, cause i still i dont get product collection :(